# Connecting two curve figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create the diagram below. However, I am having difficulties making the top portion of the curves on the right plot. Specifically, how would I make one long command to draw the shaded curve instead of two separate commands with a random line in the middle? My MWE is given below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,
            arrows.meta,
            calc,
            positioning,
            decorations.pathreplacing,
            decorations.markings,
            calligraphy,
            bending,
            shapes.geometric,
            3d,
            tikzmark,
            fit,
            matrix,
            shapes.misc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath} %Note I do not know what other packages are necessary since I have my own package that already has everything I need in it. 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Latex-Latex,thick] (0,5.5) node[above]{$E$/eV} -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,5.5);
\draw[thick,-Latex] (4.5,5.5) -- (4.5,0) -- (8.5,0);
\draw[thick] (0,-0.1) node[below]{0} -- (0,0.1);
\draw (2,-0.1) node[below]{$k$};
\draw[thick] (4,-0.1) node[below]{$\frac{\pi}{a}$} -- (4,0.1);
\draw (6.5,-0.1) node[below]{\textsc{dos}, $N(E)$};
\draw[dotted,thick] (0,4) -- (8.5,4) node[right]{$E_F$};
\draw[thick] (0,0.25) ..controls +(0:2.5) and +(180:1.5).. (4,1.5)
        node[pos=0.75,inner sep=0pt](s){};
\draw[thick] (0,3.4) ..controls +(0:3) and +(180:1.5).. (4,3.65)
        node[pos=0.75,inner sep=0pt](px){};
\draw[thick] (0,3.5) ..controls +(0:3.0) and +(180:1.5).. (4,3.75)
        node[pos=0.75,inner sep=0pt](py){};
\draw[thick] (0,4.5) ..controls +(0:3) and +(180:1.5).. (4,3)
        node[pos=0.75,inner sep=0pt](pz){};
\node[xshift=-2em] at (s) {$2s$};
\node[] at (0.8,3.1) {$2p_x$, $2p_y$};
\node[] at (0.4,4.8) {$2p_z$};
\draw [fill=black!25] (4.5,0.25) -- +(1.5,0.0) .. controls +(-1.2,0.25) and +(-1.2,-0.25) .. +(1.5,1.5) -- +(0.0,1.5) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=black!25] (4.5,3) -- +(1.5,0.0) .. controls +(-1.2,0.2) and +(-4,-0.25) .. +(3.75,0.7) -- +(0.0,0.7); 
\draw [fill=black!25] (4.5,3.7) -- +(3.75,0) .. controls +(-1.5,0.15) and +(-1.2,-0.35) .. +(0.75,0.3) -- +(0,0.3); %I want to connect this with
\draw [fill=black!25] (4.5,3) -- +(1.5,0.0) .. controls +(-1.2,0.2) and +(-4,-0.25) .. +(3.75,0.7) -- +(0.0,0.7); %this curve without horizontal line.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding what packages etc. are needed, did you test the example? I suspect you're missing the `arrows.meta` tikzlibrary at least, but test it and check if you get any errors.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. This example works fine. I just do not know how I can combine two separate lines of code into one to make the example picture.

Comment: For reference: This is a follow-up question of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/631854/95441